# How to implement setWordWrap(True) for a custom QLabel?

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm re-implementing `QLabel()` by overriding its paintEvent.

What I'm doing is, to redraw the text 3 times in order to gain an emboss effect.

I'm using **PyQT-PySide** and the application is aimed for **OS X**, which does not support Qt's brilliant effects (shadow et al.). Therefore this is the solution I came up with.

Everything works fine except, implementation of `setTextWrap(True)`. It fails.

What do I need to do to `self.text()` in order to wrap it accordingly to fit into the label's box?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the `Qt.TextWordWrap` **flag** which is then added to the **drawText()** method of `QPainter()`

Example:

```
    painter.drawText(self.rect(), self.alignment() | Qt.TextWordWrap, self.text())
```